# how to call opa functions from external scripts or embeded content like flash plugins

Tags: opa

as the title says, dos anyone know a way how to call functions I define in opa from external scripts or embeded content on the client side.

In other words, the opposite direction of what is explained in the [8. Hello, reCaptcha (and the rest of the world)](http://doc.opalang.org/index.html#hello_recaptcha) example.

In my special case I got an interactive, embeded plugin from where i can call js functions defined in the browser context. But how do I need to define them in opa, so I can call them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, one of the difficulties is to guess the name of the Opa-generated functions in JS.

In Opa, there is a directive @js_ident such that @js_ident("name_of_a_function") is the string of the function at runtime. I think, this doesn't help you much, though.

However, I think you can expose in JS a registering function (that puts its argument in reference), and call it from Opa with the Opa function you want to call as argument.

Comment: Your second idea sounds like what I came up with last night.


I wrote a Listener class as external JS and gave it a callback function from opa via BSL.


That is definitively working.


But a
@keep_the_name_and_make_the_function_accessible_from_outside
directive would be really nice. Or I just didn't find it yet...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's pretty hard, or maybe impossible. Opa javascript function are generated, so you can't really guess their name, arguments, etc...